# Will they take my Unsung Hero badge back if my answers are upvoted?

Tags: support, badges

I recently received a **unsung hero** - ***Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total***.

Do they take my badge back if my answers are upvoted? I would be grateful if someone could explain the Stack Overflow functionality behind this.

Comment: Badges are never reverted, once you earn a badge you keep it forever.

Comment: @l4mpi, except tag badges.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

First of all, congratulations! Unsung Hero is not an easy badge to achieve!

Regular badges, once earned, are *not* taken away (at least not automatically).

*Tag* badges (earned for a score + minimum number of posts in a tag) *are* taken away when you no longer meet the criteria, and if any badge was earned through heinous cheating, it is sometimes taken away manually at the discretion of the moderators (it takes a Stack Exchange developer to remove it).

But your Unsung Hero badge is safe!

Comment: then these `"Zero score accepted answers"` words may become false .Isn't ? as it is same for the case like tag badge . And why dont i have for this ?

Comment: @sankrish: You got the badge fair and square; the wording does mean *at the time you earned it*. It is a badge of honour, you deserved it!

Comment: @sankrish: as for tag badges: it is rare enough that you lose a badge, and it is not hard to re-earn it if you do.

Comment: Thanks buddy . i am happy that i wont lose my badge :)

Comment: Phew! I just got Unsung Hero and I wasn't sure how I was going to be able to keep it.

Comment: I don't know about it being an 'honour'. I just received it and realized this translates to a significant percentage of one's answers being technically correct but not of a high enough quality to merit the votes of one's fellow SO members. I suppose it's not an easy badge to get if your answers are of good quality.

Comment: @AshwinNair: there are plenty of tags on SO that don't have enough *activity* to receive votes from fellow SO members, purely because there are not enough SO members active in that tag with enough reputation to vote. If there is no-one to vote, it doesn't matter how high quality your answers are.

Comment: @Ash I got this badge since I can only answer basic beginner questions that don't get a lot of attention and the OP does not have the reputation to upvote.

Comment: I think even if the answers get upvoted later, which, at some point, might get the badge owner unqualified for the badge, they still should maintain it, because badge was earned at the specific moment of time dimension. It's like no one will strip you of your gold medal, if you won it in the previous championship, but didn't repeat the same result later on.