# Badges are not disappearing after question deletion

Tags: bug, badges

It is known that if a question that you have contribute to (comment/answer/edit) has been deleted, you will lose all the points that you have earned.

But what happens with the badges? As a new user I am earning badges 'easily' but I noticed that after a question's deletion, I didn't lose the badge (specifically the Organizer badge) that I have earned because of my contribution.

Is that right? Is that a bug? Or this is happening only in a certain types of badges?

Comment: Take a look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254656/will-they-take-my-unsung-hero-badge-back-if-my-answers-are-upvoted

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy this anwsers my question, thanks!