# How to check how many zero-score accepted answers I have

Tags: discussion, badges, accepted-answer

I just earned the Tenacious badge, for which you need to have at least 5 zero-score accepted answers and they have to be 20% of the total. I did the maths and got to 7 zero-score accepted answers on my All Answers tag. Furthermore that are only 12% of my accepted answers, which made me think why I had received this badge. One post on the meta pointed out that on a different case, even if a question get's upvoted after being accepted this get's counted into the badge progress.

My question now is, if and how I can check how many zero-score accepted answers I have.

**EDIT:** See this [answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254656/4348873)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straightforward enough search to perform:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3Ayes+score%3A0

Main things:

- `user:me` (or a specific user ID)
- `is:answer` must be specified
- `isaccepted:yes` must be specified to get only accepted answers
- `score:0` to get specifically zero-score answers

The [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) worked in the end.

Comment: This returns the answers that right now have a score 0. However I need to also find the ones that had a score of 0 when being accepted but then got upvotes, as this still counts to the Unsung Hero Badge

Comment: That's not something that simple search can express.  You may need to look into [SEDE.](http://data.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @JulianE. check if any of [these](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=tenacious) can help

Comment: Yeah, they helo:-) Help Thanks. The SEDE did the trick as it has the exact result I am looking for under how UNSUNG am I?