# How often is SEDE updated?

Tags: discussion, support, data-explorer

I am currently trying to go for the Unsung Hero badge in order to get a new hat on the Winter Bash 2015.

Now, to the actual question. I have asked in the past on how to find how many zero-score accepted answers I have and got linked to two resources. The one being to perform a simple search as followed:

> Straightforward enough search to perform:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3Ayes+score%3A0
>
> Main things:
>
> - `user:me` (or a specific user ID)
> - `is:answer` must be specified
> - `isaccepted:yes` must be specified to get only accepted answers
> - `score:0` to get specifically zero-score answers

(Taken from my previous question that can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312223/how-to-check-how-many-zero-score-accepted-answers-i-have).)

If I do this, it return that I have 10 zero-score accepted answers and a total of 32 questions.

[image: Screenshot Query]

This results in a 31% of the total.

However when using the SEDE with this query: [How unsung am I?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i)

It tells me that I have 27 accepted answers and only 6 unscored ones.
[image: screenshot SEDE]

Therefore my question is. How often does the SEDE update its database and the data used for the queries?

Or if it is correct is it possibly a bug on either Search or SEDE?

Comment: Every Sunday morning.  The query result is accurate, subtract one because it was your own question, subtract three that were not yet accepted on Sunday, they'll show up next Sunday.  It is your lucky week.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that up @HansPassant! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [SEDE FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help):

> How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?
>
> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Dec 13 at 6:27.