# How can we handle a user who sabotaged dozens of their old questions and answers and then deleted their account?

Tags: discussion, deleted-users, vandalism

Recently I noticed a user had edited dozens of their old questions and answers. In many cases they were removing code and just leaving some short amount of original text. I flagged one of the questions for moderator attention and I left a comment to the OP on one of the edited questions asking why they were sabotaging their posts.

Today I see the user account has been removed. I also see that most of their edited posts are showing as being last edited by "Community bot".

You can see many of these by viewing the [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) tag and sorting by Activity. Scroll down a bit and then you will see a few pages of edits by "Community bot" all starting on about August 19, 2023.

The user id of the deleted user is user141302.

Many of the sabotaged questions don't make any sense any more after the edits. Many of the sabotaged answers had been marked as the accepted answer, but now they are worthless in their current state.

I've rolled back the changes (and cleaned up) a couple of these posts. But there are dozens. Is there a procedure to get all of these edits rolled back? Or is my original flag all that is needed?

Comment: Flag for moderator help on this one by attaching a custom flag on one of the user's existing questions or answers, explaining this and they will eventually (hopefully) take care of it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Do you mean a 2nd flag in addition to my original one?

Comment: No, one should do. That's it. I don't think that asking on meta is necessary for this sort of thing, if you've already adequately flagged it.

Comment: I'd *guess* the user decided to vandalise their content to hide things, such as code they weren't supposed to share, and then also deleted their account to attempt to avoid traceability. The problem is that they don't understand that as soon as they posted the code it was licenced under CC-BY-SA. If they didn't have the right to post that content, then they should have contacted [so], or owned up to their error and the owner of the content could have contacted the company. The content presumably will be restored but there's a back log of flags at the moment, so it light take a little while.

Comment: @ThomA normally a reasonable theory, but... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22067983/revisions)'s one example, which is just lopping off "Does not Xcode 5 allow to code using MRC as it supports ARC? Can we use only ARC in Xcode 5?" with a false "Improve english" edit message.  Also, aaaaaaaaaaargh.

Comment: @ThomA The few I've looked at have some pretty basic code. There certainly weren't any trade secrets being violated. Most of the questions and answers were from 2009/2010. And oddly, most of the edit comments the user made are simply "Improve English". Strange since most of the edits only remove code and leave the descriptions as-is.

Comment: Oh, great, there are [vandalized answers](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16352013/revisions), too... wondering if there's any way to find these more efficiently than looking through all 612 of their posts :-\ (I'm assuming there might have been deletions, too, before they hit the rate limit)

Comment: Yeah, I just had a look at a few and the edits are honestly just odd. According to a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1776906?OwnerName=user141302) it was 51 posts, but questions and answers, they likely "touched".

Comment: See my above comment, @RyanM . Sorry it doesn't have links (I'll edit to make one shortly).

Comment: @ThomA Amazing, thanks.  I can add links.

Comment: Done anyway, @RyanM : [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1776906?OwnerName=user141302)

Comment: @RyanM I see that you and one or two others have rolled back a few of these answers and questions. Is this being done manually? If so, I can pitch in on a bunch. But if there's some trick you have to do it all automatically I'll stay out of the way.

Comment: @HangarRash Manually, I don't think there's any trick that I know of.

Comment: Quasi-relatedly, the Community user also deleted a bunch of their less well-received questions when the user account was deleted. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216226/image-on-every-page-in-iphone-application, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523796/how-to-add-uiview-animation-transition-in-mailcomposerviewcontroller.  Not sure if it's worth doing anything about those.

Comment: [Relevant feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392411/165261) inspired by this.

Comment: As of now, all 50+ recently edited questions and answers by this user have been rolled back. At least based on the SEDE post provided by @ThomA.

Comment: "What is `NSParameterAssert`?" ⇒ "What is stackoverexchange?" [[link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2521275/revisions)] shows that trade secrets were probably not the issue. Ostensibly, they merely wanted to understand when `stack / exchange` causes an overflow.

Comment: Monitor for rapid edits of multiple questions/answers by the same user and limit if their activity appears to be suspicious?

Comment: With the pivot from 'users helping users' to 'users feeding an AI' that SO is going for, can you blame them?

Comment: @Hans Kilian: It may be closer to: from 'users feeding a search engine' (blindly copy-pasting from one of top results) to 'users feeding an AI'. There is a lot of undetected plagiarism on Stack Overflow from before [December 2022](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

Comment: Isn't it their data and aren't they allowed to remove it?

Comment: Does it say anywhere that a user is *not* allowed to make such changes to their own postings? I notice in [Section 6](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) of the Terms of Service that this issue isn't catered for. Technically if they change their post, are you supposed to honor their changes, even if it it means that they're defacing their own posts? (I would not consider this vandalism, as the content is their own posting and still fits the creative commons licensing).

Comment: On top of this, if the user does not have permission to post the actual information and/or code (for instance, when the copyright actually belongs to the organisation they work for, rather than themselves), would this create a [copyright infringement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#copyright) requiring the original user to remove such content?...

Comment: @Paul perhaps, but all of that is unrelated to what's going on. A user can delete their own post whole-sale (unless it was accepted). In other cases they can, themselves, flag for moderator attention. I've done this in the past when my accepted answer was obsolete a new answer should be accepted instead, e.g.

Comment: Not knowing any details, but could it be that the user had some pressure from the employer to remove all code he has "published"? As @Paul suspected, too

Comment: Here is a web archive of the users's profile: http://web.archive.org/web/20151208003143/http://stackoverflow.com/users/141302/jeffwood. It's old so all the users's posts might not be there, but at least some are.

Comment: @Yani I believe that a user is not allowed to remove their questions and answers. I suspect this is probably against the GDPR, but I'm not a lawyer, although I think it's a very shady practice and a reason that I try to keep my involvement in this site to an absolute minimum wherever possible.

Comment: Fixing is one thing, and preventing is another one even more efficient. Raise awareness for StackOverflow to implement algorithms to check when a user suddenly starts to modify more than one question and answer with lot of votes, that haven't been edited with some times now, and to block the edits until further checkup. For existing cases, it's gonna be tough though.

Comment: @zippy72 - As I pointed out in my response, there's nothing in the Ts & Cs that prevent a user from removing their own posts.

Comment: @user1945782 - there isn't, but when I've tried it before my comments and posts have been restored by mods

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Flag one of the affected posts, with any additional information you have on how to find the others.  If you can only find one, that's fine too - we can at least find all the user's posts, even if [the tooling to find the affected ones specifically is a bit lacking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392411/165261).

If you're feeling inspired and you have edit privileges, you can also use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1776906?OwnerName=user141302) (thanks to [Thom A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/thom-a)) with the appropriate username swapped in to find and roll back any non-deleted affected posts.  But ideally, also flag it, since there might be some deleted posts, which you won't be able to find (mods will have a tricky time of it, too, but it's at least possible, and/or we could ask a CM to run a query on internal SEDE, etc.).

Comment: What does "internal SEDE" mean?

Comment: We all have access to Stack Exchange Data Explorer. But members of Stack Overflow staff have access to internal-use databases that provide additional information. In this case, the author's user ID of deleted posts would be available, which is *not* available on the public SEDE.

Comment: While that SEDE query by @ThomA was very useful, can it be updated to be even better? While the "last updated" column made it easy to see the 50+ posts the user had most recently edited, there was no way to tell which ones had been fixed. There were 3 or 4 of us manually fixing those posts yesterday. It would have been really helpful if that query had some sort of column that would give an indication that the post had been further edited or rolled back. Otherwise you have to click on every link to see what still needs editing.

Comment: @HangarRash unfortunately SEDE is [only updated once a week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312514/20091109), so the query can't be fixed to account for further edits or rollbacks that have been made since yesterday, until next week.

Comment: @Stuckat1337 Oh. Good thing this user sabotaged their posts just before that refresh or it would have taken a week to see what they did.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan-onstrike If you click the link to SEDE in the question you'll see that it takes you to the Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Comment: I would suggest an "internal SEDE" is meant to mean one where certain data isn't removed @SyedM.Sannan-onstrike . For example the SEDE I provided that Ryan links to cannot handle Deleted Posts as the `PostWithDeleted` table contains very little data about the post other than its content, and its creation and deletion dates. Details of who created the post, are removed.