# Disciplined Badge too easy to be cheated

Tags: discussion, badges

I just have noticed: if you delete a post with score of 3 (or more) you get the 'Disciplined Badge' losing the post and the reputation earned on it; then undeleting it you get back the post/points plus the 'Disciplined Badge' remains with you.

1. Is it supposed to be like this?
2. Would an admin revoke the awarded badge if this "trick" becomes noticed?

*There's some users confusing the 'Disciplined Badge' with the 'Peer Pressure Badge'. So, to let it clear:*

> **Disciplined Badge:** Delete own post with score of 3 or higher.

Comment: How do you propose this could be "fixed"?

Comment: @Cerbrus since the earn badge event is attached on the specific post (at least on the notification message); the reactivation of this post could undo the badge;

Comment: Another similar thing : You cannot take back your downvote or upvote from some posted answer after sometime until the answerer make an edit to his/her answer. However if you have privillige of editing others post,  to revoke your vote, you just need to edit that answer, save it back and revoke your vote...Is  n't it fishy..........

Comment: Quickly @freestock.tk delete this question, and then un delete it, so that you get a free badge xD

Comment: @dingo_d you are right I still don't have it on here (meta) and the current post already allows this possibility;

Comment: @nobalG very interesint point (agreed); you could open a question with it here on meta;

Comment: Opened once, was heavily downvoted :p

Comment: Other than the tag specific badges, all other badges are meaningless anyway aren't they? Seems a bit pointless to spend any effort on anything like this if it doesn't affect user privileges.

Comment: This is a problem for lots of badges. The critic badge can be earned by doing a downvote, and then reversing it before the vote gets locked. Same for the Supporter badge, just that it is for a upvote. Actually even I owned the disciplined badge like this. I had disable pop-ups, and by mistakenly clicked on delete instead of edit. When reversed, I noticed I had earned the disciplined badge.

Comment: Seems like the challenge here isn't cheating the badge, it's getting a 3 point question with no answers!

Comment: It's a bronze badge, who cares about them anyway? Badges don't give privileges or anything like that.

Comment: @remus: you can earn the disciplined badge with an answer, too. Still not *easy* to get 3 points nowadays (though I guess it depends on the subject matter), but at least you're not also depending on not getting answers.

Comment: Cross-site MSE dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95918/i-cheated-on-the-disciplined-badge-how-bad-is-it

Comment: @nobalG: when you do that, you reveal yourself as it’s easy to understand the “post was edited”+“voting changed” sequence and it will be logged who made the edit.

Comment: @Holger not 100% sure, since it could be a coincidence (another user edit the post and you take advantage of it to undo your vote);

Comment: I think the Disciplined badge holds a lot more value than you think, especially for the new users and the users who have very low reputation (e.g. : myself). For them, posts that have 3 or more reputation are pretty rare (unless they've hit jackpot with one special post which went viral), and deleting such posts takes courage, because they're sacrificing potential upvotes in the future. For someone who has loads of such posts or has a large amount of reputation, that's easier.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Badges will not be taken away, even if at some point the criteria for achieving them is not met any more.

> Regular badges, once earned, are not taken away (at least not automatically).
>
> Tag badges (earned for a score + minimum number of posts in a tag) are taken away when you no longer meet the criteria, and if any badge was earned through heinous cheating, it is sometimes taken away manually at the discretion of the moderators (it takes a Stack Exchange developer to remove it).

<sup>(Taken from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254656/will-they-take-my-unsung-hero-badge-back-if-my-answers-are-upvoted))</sup>

So yes, it is supposed to be like this, whether it seems good or not.

IMHO, Pekka 웃 made a very good point about this in his (now deleted) [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320512/disciplined-badge-too-easy-to-be-cheated?noredirect=1#comment330615_320512):

> badges exist mainly for an educational purpose. Someone gaming the badge has arguably done what the system wants them to do - learn about how an aspect of it works

---

*To address your update:* I do not think it would be feasible for mods to manually remove the badge once awarded, as there would probably be way too many users doing this (nothing I can prove). But further, this is currently not even possible for "standard" mods, as - like mentioned above:

> it takes a Stack Exchange developer to remove it

meaning a lot of work for a small amount of people.

---

There are actually quite a lot of badges that can be "cheated" in a similar manner:

- Scholar *"Ask a question and accept an answer"*
- Autobiographer *"Complete "About Me" section of user profile"*
- Commentator *"Leave 10 comments*"
- Critic *"First down vote"*
- Disciplined *"Delete own post with score of 3 or higher"*
- Peer Pressure *"Delete own post with score of -3 or lower"*
- Suffrage *"Use 30 votes in a day"*
- Supporter *"First up vote "*
- Vox Populi *"Use the maximum 40 votes in a day"*
- (Informed)* *"Read the entire tour page"*

<sub>*Sort of. You can't undo the action but you do not necessarily have to read the page</sub>

Notice, how every one of those badges is a bronze one. This supports the argument, that those badges are only for educational purposes, to invite you to try new features. It even says so on the right sidebar of [the badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

> Bronze badges encourage users to try out new features on the site. They are easy to get if you try!

Comment: I "cheated" to get the peer pressure badge, now I regret it. It wasn't a bad answer, didn't deserve being deleted even if it was only for few seconds.

Comment: Now if only people would stop giving me upvoted answers on my (very few!) 3+ questions so I could delete one ;)

Comment: @MichaelB-AzureMVP: answers are "posts".  I always assumed "disciplined" was intended for people deleting upvoted answers once they realized the answer was wrong.

Comment: wonder why he deleted that comment. Did he think he would get a badge for it? ;)

Comment: @CubeJockey I had commented, asking whether he would be alright with me, citing his comment - he agreed. Those got deleted as well. I reckon they got flagged and deleted as obsolete but I have no idea

Comment: @T3H40 yep, I remember seeing both of those

Comment: Np. Konami code doesn't work though - I tried;)

Comment: + **Mortarboard "*Earn at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day.*"** I believe this one is cheated often, be it intentionally or as a victim. I received it when a spam vote account upvoted many of my posts and was reversed the next day. I'd really have rather earned that badge on my own merit. -_-

Comment: How do you cheat autobiographer?

Comment: @ArtemisFowl Someone else writes your biography for you?

Comment: @c.helling Quite. I guess when creating joining a new network, your about me is carried across, but still.

Comment: @artemis fowl You could always "fkskfkdjfhsjcjs" away on your keyboard and delete it afterwards. The idea of "cheating" a badge as for this post is to perform an action and undo it again after you got the achievement

Comment: @T3H40 True, fair enough.

Answer (score 43):

Bronze badges are ones that in the main are designed to introduce you to some feature of the system that you've not tried before and that you may not know about.

If you delete your post, you lose the rep it gained, it's possible you've never done that before and not realised it, well now you know and when you undelete it you learn that you get the rep back again. Maybe you didn't even realise you could delete your own upvoted posts prior to doing this.

Whether you undelete it or not you've learned something about how Stack Overflow works so that's one justification of why you should keep the badge.

Comment: I think the key issue here is whether you can get the badge multiple times or only once. I can see why someone could get annoyed if people start earning an insane amount of bronze badges by deleting and undeleting stuff...

Comment: @user000001 In this case (as is the case with almost all non-tag bronze badges) you can get it only once.

Answer (score 18):

In Minecraft, you earn an achievement just for opening your inventory. The achievement is called, well, 'Taking Inventory'. Many games work like this, and Stack Overflow was influenced by game design.

The list of bronze badges are similar to a list of in-game achievements that are mostly darkened out, with a few glimmering to get your attention, also serving as prerequisites for the more advanced achievements. The faster you eat all of that low-hanging fruit, the sooner you know most of the basic aspects of gameplay; for well-designed games, anyway.

If you don't make the very early steps in a game easy enough for people to accomplish, they won't see as much value in continuing to unlock privileges that facilitate the kind of community moderation that we have. Yes, bronze badges are primarily there for discovery - but a few of them earned quickly can make a big difference in someone capable coming back and continuing to develop their account, or just abandoning it after a few days.

You know that you *can* delete an upvoted answer if you figure out that it was totally wrong or even dangerous, and that's the point of the badge. That you shot a few <strike>toes</strike> rep off for a few moments is more of a temporary and ancillary inconvenience ;)

Comment: +50 just for the Minecraft reference. (I'm back on a Minecraft kick, ignore me.) On a more serious note, I'd be surprised if there weren't at least a handful of users who didn't realize they could do this until they decided to glance through the badge list one day... Teaches them to clean up after themselves so the community doesn't have to. In turn making this answer all the more on-point.