# Do you lose the right to answer a question if you used your re-open hammer?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

On a related question I noticed this upvoted [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361469/is-it-possible-to-know-who-single-handedly-reopened-a-question#comment545155_361471):

> If you see a user repeatedly reopening duplicate questions just to answer them, that's definitely worth a comment and if they don't reply / adjust their behaviour, a mod flag is in order

If this is true then we need to flag around [3335 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/778171) of several users, ironically enough including the OP of the question I found that comment on, but also several moderators, like Martijn Pieters, deceze, a few members of the close vote gang of [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and other well known, high rep contributors (yes, even Jon Skeet is in that list).

Being close to getting a dupe hammer myself, I would like to know if I'm exempt from answering questions after I single-handedly reopened them, or more general: what is the real problem with that behavior, even so that we want moderators to be bothered with it?

I don't fancy getting flagged for using features I'm privileged to use.

Comment: The comment says *"reopening duplicate questions"*, not *"reopening questions closed as duplicates"*. The distinction is important. If it said the latter, I'd agree with everything you say here, but it doesn't say that.

Comment: With a dupe hammer comes the expectation that you understand when something is a duplicate. Sometimes we misunderstand what a question is about, sometimes someone else has misunderstood. Reopening and answering is fine in the majority of such cases.

Comment: The issue there is that apparently someone felt that the dupe target was too low quality. At that point I personally would have strived to find a better dupe or work with the community (chat room) to find a better target.

Comment: In any case, I feel that the situation there could have been avoided by proactively communicating your reasons. “I’m reopening this because ...”.

Comment: @MarkAmery I obviously don't understand that distinction and I still don't. Let me know if I need to take this to ELL.se if this becomes more like an English comprehension exercise.

Comment: @rene the comment is presuming that the questions *actually are* duplicates (and therefore ought to be closed). Though it could be more explicit, it's (I think) trying to say "if a user repeatedly reopens *actual, correctly closed* duplicates in order to answer them, flag them". You're responding to it as though it said "if a user repeatedly reopens questions that have been *rightly or wrongly* closed as duplicates, flag them". As Cerbrus says in his answer, the problem is (only) when these questions were closed *properly*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, what you describe all sounds reasonable but still leaves me with the feeling that without leaving comments I run the risk of getting mod-flagged while doing *The Right Thing* which is providing valuable content to this site. Something seems off in the emotional reaction and support that comment I linked to receives. I see the same discussions in SOCVR, I simply don't get it, that's all.

Comment: (Though note also @MartijnPieters comments above - there are legitimate, non-corrupt reasons to reopen and answer even a genuine duplicate question, such as the dupe target being much lower quality. I hadn't thought about that when I left my first comment, and I suspect Glorfindel hadn't thought about it when he left the comment you're quoting either. In that sense, you're right to criticise the comment; it's missing an important nuance.)

Comment: @MarkAmery that makes a lot more sense. Thanks for explaining that to me.

Comment: Yeah, my comment is missing the words "properly closed" before "duplicate questions". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No, problem @Glorfindel at least I practiced my SQL parsing skills once more ...

Comment: @rene 998 votes on C#. Don't you like the moment _just before_ you get the badge ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if anyone wants to prevent that from happening, this is their chance. After that I only will cause havoc ...

Comment: @rene rest assured if someone is mod flagged for abuse of their hammer privileges it will be reviewed thoroughly and not taken as gospel based on a single occurrence. Being flagged is really not something to worry about here.

Comment: Related reading: [How well should gold badge holders prove the correctness of their unhammering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359059/424903)

Comment: @cerbrus im not sure where you heard that but that is false. If when the dupehammer allocation script runs you no longer have the qualifications for the gold tag badge, you will no longer have the badge or the privileges associated with it, just like any other badge or tag badge.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Orly? That's new to me. Removing the misinformation...

Comment: @Cerbrus that's what I tought: if someone DV you on 1000 points to 999 you lose the badge (happened to me when I was on the 3000 rep boundary and someone unaccepted my answer: my right for instant edit was revoked ... during 10 minutes, those were fastuous times :))

Comment: *The* significant difference between tag badges and regular badges is that [tag badges will be revoked if you no longer qualify for them, while you do not loose non-tag badges for which you no longer qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254657/3773011).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether you have gold-hammer or are regular user it is perfectly fine to re-open and answer question provided you make sure the question no longer looks duplicate by standard guidance -  ["This question may already have an answer here" - but it does not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not).

It is your responsibility to make sure that the question contains clear and valid explanation why it is not duplicate (for suggested duplicate as well as other possible duplicates) before re-opening. Being gold-hammer user in the tag makes validation or authoring of such clarification much easier than for other users (as you presumably have plenty of knowledge in the tag's space and likely have full edit privileges) - so there is no excuse to skip that part of re-open process. I believe it is reasonable to make an edit to the question in line with

> "The {link_to_question} covers similar topic and suggests XXXX, but this one is about YYYY which can't be solved by XXXX because of ..."

If you don't see such explanation and can't add one - the question should stay closed as duplicate. You may consider editing list of duplicates if you have better one. If you feel it may not be duplicate - add comment explaining why it *may* be non-duplicate so OP has more information to clarify question and get it re-opened.

Note: as person experienced in technology covered by particular tag you may see question "clearly not duplicate" for reasons that are hard to notice by majority of users - keep that in mind and make sure everyone (with some experience in the given technology) can see the reason. Consider editing question to make it clear.

Some more discussion on re-open etiquette is [How well should gold badge holders prove the correctness of their unhammering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359059/how-well-should-gold-badge-holders-prove-the-correctness-of-their-unhammering)

Comment: It can be helpful if the question has been edited to explain why it is not a dupe, but I don't in any way see that as a *requirement* for re-opening.  Questions are sometimes closed erroneously, and in that case they should be reopened, period.  Whether a closure was erroneous can, of course, be controversial, and an explanation in the question can help with that.  So, however, can an *answer*.

Answer (score 53):

The problem isn't necessarily in answering a question you re-opened.
The problem is when these questions were closed properly.

Re-opening a rightfully closed question in order to answer it is not done. It's abuse of a privilege one earned.

You're expected to understand what is and isn't a duplicate, and you're trusted not to abuse the tools you're given.

Comment: Fair enough, so as long as I can explain why a question wasn't closed properly I should be fine, no matter how often I do re-open hammer closed duplicates.

Comment: Aye, that's the gist of it.

Comment: @rene If you're reopening a question to answer it, typically the answer itself speaks to why you reopened the question.  If you're posting an answer that's radically different than what's in what used to be the duplicate target, then you've *demonstrated* how you think the answer to the current question is different from the other one.  It's even better than just *stating* that you think the answers are different.  If you post an answer that just says what the old dup target says, then you've *demonstrated* that the reopening wasn't appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Cerbrus' excellent answer:

If you're a gold badge user, and you see an unproperly closed question, you should try to ping (possibly manually since he/she may not have commented) the closer to try to make *him/her* reopen before using their hammer to reopen.

Most of the time, when the technical arguments are okay, the person agrees and reopens (and you can craft your answer in the meantime :))

If the person doesn't respond and you really feel that the question isn't a duplicate (of *no other question* as well, or in that case, edit and *change* the duplicate, without reopening), then, reopen, comment why you reopened & if you have an answer, then answer. That's not abusing.

(If you feel that you don't have to ask permission, well, don't, but at least comment/ping the person who closed to explain why you're reopening.)

Comment: I'd say making it about one user (or a small set of users) kind of undermines the principle of community moderation. If you're **sure** that the question should be reopened, you should reopen it. If not, you shouldn't (if unsure, you should seek clarification). If this leads to repeated closing and reopening, consensus should be reached on Meta or via moderators. As someone who regularly votes to close, I'd rather just have any given question be reopened instead of being asked to reconsider my close vote.

Comment: The opposite would be: reopen without comment, then answer, without notifying anyone. At least leave some explanation.

Comment: But will the comment to the hammer-closer go through?

Comment: @user000001 there's a "timeout" if the closer doesn't respond. At least you tried.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: But it is (almost) pointless to comment to someone it he won't get a notification. What are the chances of him returning to the thread?

Comment: comment & ping him manually of course with explicit "@"

Comment: @user000001 dupehammers are pingable on questions they've hammered. Other closers are not pingable that way.

Comment: @Jean Only users who have edited the question, commented on the question, or have single-handedly closed or reopened (and IIRC deleted / undeleted) the post. Basically you have to have interacted with the post to be pingable, and regular closers are not pingable.

Comment: @TinyGiant hell! better learn that now than in 2 years. That's why when I tried to ping some expert on the subject on some post he/she never replied! thanks for this invaluable info.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If the question really is different, and you're reopening it to post an answer, then [the answer *is* an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361472/do-we-lose-the-right-to-answer-a-question-if-you-used-your-re-open-hammer#comment545319_361473).  If it's not clear from your answer how the question isn't answered by the duplicate, then you haven't posted a good answer, so posting a comment explaining the reopening isn't what you should be worried about.

Comment: @Servy agreed 100% (although I always like to comment by respect to the former dupe-closer). That wasn't the case earlier today where the answers were the same/slightly worse than the originals :)

Comment: FWIW, I agree that while it's not _necessary_ to ping the original closer when you want a question un-hammered, it's still nice etiquette IMHO. I've occasionally hammered Python questions incorrectly, and I'm more than happy to un-hammer once my error is pointed out, either via a comment or in the chat room. I'd rather un-hammer it myself than have someone else waste a re-open vote due to my error.