# Number of posts edited reduced

Tags: discussion, edits, statistics, activity-tab

I had been keeping track of the "Posts Edited" count on the activity tab as there is a badge award at the 80 mark (not a big deal). I passed this some weeks ago but noticed that the count is now at 78, reducing by about 4 or 5. It struck me as a bit odd - and I still have the "Strunk & White" badge.

I can't find information that would reduce the "Posts Edited" count specifically though I did come across a post about rep for an edit that got reverted due to the OP deleting their post.

Does this apply to the "Posts Edited" count as well?

Comment: I'm guessing some of the posts you edited were deleted. But badges once earned will stay. (Tag badges being the exception).

Comment: @S.L.Barth, that thought occurred as well but 4-5 posts at once seems a bit odd in and of itself. Not exactly worried about the badge - it's only a small number of posts, it's more the unusual nature of it.

Comment: Maybe the posts weren't deleted at the same time, but only within the same interval of the badge script. Or maybe you edited multiple answers on a now-deleted question, then they could be deleted all at the same time.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, that's entirely possible. I guess we'd only have surety from the SO devs as to what underpins the count.

Comment: 5 posts can be deleted at once, when a question that already has 4 answers gets deleted.

Comment: It's totally normal. If you edit several questions on a day and they don't get an answer and get a downvote, they'll be deleted after 30 days (roomba). I guess it happened already before, but you maybe didn't notice, one day you maybe had 54 edits, next day only 52. With over 2000 points, you don't get rep. for edits anymore, but users under 2000 will also lose 2 point for the deleted post.

Comment: @jps That actually happened to me once or twice, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: @pnuts: What are you trying to achieve? That's the 48th question you edited in the last 24h. Most of them are old questions, a lot of them are closed and/or resolved. Are you trying to burnate tags on meta?

Comment: there's something odd. i've been stuck at posts edited between 427-429 always changing within this range for the past days even though i kept editing posts. il update this thread again after a week if i'm still in that range.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deleted posts don't contribute to the edit count.

- Deleting a post will decrease your edit count if you had edits on it.
- Editing a deleted post will not affect your edit count.
- Undeleting a post will increase your edit count if you had edits on it.

Rollbacks don't affect other edits. They actually count as 1 edit.

Changing the post to a community wiki post doesn't affect edit count.

[De-attributing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288274/please-implement-clause-7b-of-the-cc-by-sa-license/288276#288276) yourself from a post will decrease your edit count accordingly (rare process requiring admin powers above the elected ♦ powers).

---

"Strunk & White" is a kind of badge that [you can't lose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254657/1033581), even if you later fall below the requirement to get it.

---

Deleting and undeleting also affect reputation gains through approved edits in a review queue, as demonstrated by jps:

1. This [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17216073) granted 2 reputation to jps on Sep 2 '17.
2. The 2 points are now missing from [jps reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7329832/jps?tab=reputation) for that day, since the question is deleted.

But note that reputation earned through edits for posts with a score of 3 or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, **may be retained** if we follow the logic of [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222).

Comment: deleted posts definitely affect the rep. you gained for editing them: https://imgur.com/a/BFLmQqq Had several such cases in the past.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46012183/gpy-is-working-in-poweshell-but-not-in-idle-or-jupyter-and-m-plot-does-not-gen

Comment: also worth to note: deleting a post will decrease your edit count, but it will not decrease the 'helpful flags' and 'votes cast' counts.