# Can badges be lost once earned?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, electorate-badge

Are badges permanent once they have been earned? Consider the criteria required to earn the **electorate** badge;

[image]

Once you have earned a badge, if you subsequently fall below the required criteria (in this case, if my ratio of votes on questions fell below 25%), would I lose this badge?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will they take my Unsung Hero badge back if my answers are upvoted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254656/will-they-take-my-unsung-hero-badge-back-if-my-answers-are-upvoted) *Mind that the first answer also mentions tag badges!*

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you. I guess my searches were too electorate specfic.